# Failed to sent event to MongoDB using Logstash caused by wrong argument number

Tags: mongodb, logstash, logstash-configuration

I am trying to push some logs to my local MongoDB instance using Logstash with the configuration as follow:

```
   output{
 mongodb {
         id => "mongo-aws-cloudtrail"
         collection => "aws-cloudtrail"
         database => "unified-log"
         uri => "mongodb://localhost:27017/unified-log"
         codec => "json"
      }
}
```

Unfortunately, it gave an error message like this:

> [WARN ] 2019-05-06 17:49:24.658 [[main]>worker3] mongodb - Failed to
>   send event to MongoDB, retrying in 3 seconds
>   {:event=>#, :exception=>#}

Any ideas why it generates this error?

Comment: I also have same issue. Please comment u got any solution.https://discuss.elastic.co/t/failed-to-send-event-to-mongodb-retrying-in-3-seconds-event-logstash-0x2367ca72-exception-argumenterror-wrong-number-of-arguments-2-for-1/208652                  https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-output-mongodb/issues/68